# What is the legal status of [A Declaration for the Future of the Internet]?

Tags: international-law, internet

On the [State.Gov website](https://www.state.gov/declaration-for-the-future-of-the-internet), the 3 page document called [A Declaration for the Future of the Internet] can be found, and a number of countries are listed at the bottom who supposedly are *participating* in this declaration.

However, I am somewhat concerned about the seriousness of this document, considering that (1) the typographic design choices are odd. All the text has been placed within a frame, and there is unncecessary emphasis on fancy typography. (2) While there has been some press coverage about this, they have been relatively low in volume.

What is the legal status of this document? Is it binding to the participatory countries as a matter of law? Can a court strike down a local law that runs contrary to the values described in this document? Are the participating countries obligated to enforce laws that guarantee that these values are upheld?

Comment: As to the typography, I think they're trying to give it a vaguely 18th-century look, perhaps trying to evoke connotations of an enlightenment-era bill of rights. Culturally, it looks American to me, and Americans like formal documents to look old-fashioned, witness their bank notes.

Comment: @MichaelKay I cannot say if it looks American, but it certainly does not look like internet-age typography

Answer (score 11):

- What is the legal status of this document?

It has no legal status.

- Is it binding to the participatory countries as a matter of law?

No.

- Can a court strike down a local law that runs contrary to the values described in this document?

No.

- Are the participating countries obligated to enforce laws that guarantee that these values are upheld?

Not until the country accedes to a treaty containing specific obligations.

---

From [The Declaration for the Future of the Internet Is for Wavering Democracies, Not China and Russia](https://www.lawfareblog.com/declaration-future-internet-wavering-democracies-not-china-and-russia), May 6, 2022.

> The statement was signed by 61 nations and aims to establish a code of practice for how democratic countries should engage with the web. The declaration’s vision for the internet is broad—aspiring to promote universal internet access, protect human rights, ensure fair economic competition, design secure digital infrastructure, promote pluralism and freedom of expression, and guarantee a multi-stakeholder approach to internet governance. While this is an ambitious scope for a three-page **nonbinding document**, the priorities are admirable and reflect the diverse interests of the signatories.

Comment: Depending on a country's own constitutional arrangements (especially if you're a particularly dualist country like, say the UK), even ratifying a treaty might not create an obligation you could sue for, at least until it was translated into domestic law.